# vim iTerm ssh: cannot copy and paste ("Copy" is disabled with text selected)

Tags: ssh, vim, mouse, copy-paste, iterm2

I'm using iTerm2. If I'm using vim on local works fine and I can copy some text from my vim session with mouse.

Now I'm connecting to a debian 7, running vim with the same configuration. I select text but now I can't copy: in the contextual menu (right click), the `Copy` function is disabled.  How can I copy?

My .vimrc: https://github.com/arnaudlamy/config/blob/master/.vim/.vimrc

Comment: Try removing `set mouse+=a` or setting it to another value.

Comment: Try hold `Alt` when select

Comment: I do need the option mouse+=a to click on vim menus (like NerdTree). Alt deactivate the mouse+=a and allow the copy paste ! It works ! Thank you both for your answer !

Answer (score 7):

Press the ⌥ `option` key (also known as the `Alt` key), and then select text.

Comment: Technically it's `opt`, not `alt`, but yes, this works, thanks...